# Unit test with TcpClient Mock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tcpclient

I have a middleware server written by Nancy and I have a function to connect to another server using TcpClient.
I when I write a unit test for this function, I can not mock a TcpClient object and setup Connect or GetStream function.

I need help.

Comment: Then encapsulate the client behind an abstraction so that is can mocked out when unit testing in isolation. You don't actually want to unit test the `TcpClient` as that would have already be done the its developers.

Comment: Show how the client is integrated into you code in a [mcve] so that a refactoring can be done

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi, I know It's not necessary to test the func of TcpClient because we need to mock the result of TcpClient but we can not do that now.

Comment: You completely missed the point I was making in the first sentence.

Comment: Ok I got it.
Thanks